# User defined logger

Tags: java, log4j

I am quite new to the Log4j . I am having a few questions on root logger and user defined logger.

1. On what basis  should we create user defined logger (Project specific or class specific or any thing else)?
2. When to create root logger?

Answer (score 2):

1. At your heart's content. The common practice is to create one logger per class with the excerpt:

   ```java
   Logger l = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
   ```

   You don't need to worry that it you'll create too many loggers, log4j creates only one per given name.
2. Root logger is always created by log4j.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a user defined logger when you want to have:

- different "additivity" level from the root logger (true/false)
- different logging level (DEBUG, ERROR,...)
- different appender

  ```
  <logger name="my.package.Class" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="MYAPPENDER"/>
  ```

I use it this way:

```
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class);
```

If you just want a simple logging system you can use the root logger.